# Erro "esta pagina não está funcionando" em site hospedado no AWS

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-aws

Estou configurando a hospedagem de um site PHP em um servidor gratuiuto da AWS, a pagina inicial de login está aparecendo corretamente, e quando eu confirmo o `form` de login, ele vai para a página que verifica os dados de login, e se os dados estão corretos, ele vai para a pagina principal, e se algo da errado ele volta para a pagina de login com a mensagem de erro por `GET`, porém ao carregar a pagina de verificação ele da o erro de `Esta página não está funcionando`, fiz alguns testes dando `echo` em algumas partes do código para verificar onde que ele está "travando" e acabei descobrindo que o erro é na parte de conexão ao banco de dados, que está hospedado no Hostgator. 
Código da função que conecta ao banco de dados:

```
function conectardb(){
        $conexao = mysqli_connect('host', 'usuario', 'senha', 'banco');
        //testar a conexao
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "FALHA NA CONEXÃO";
        }

        return $conexao;
    }
```

O código acima está em uma pagina separada, porém tentei usar na mesma página e o erro persiste. Ele não chega a printar o `FALHA NA CONEXÃO` no `if`.

O mesmo código de conexão, se conectando ao mesmo host do Hostgator está funcionando corretamente quando o site está hospedado localmente.

Gostaria de saber se alguém ja passou por uma situação parecida ou tem alguma ideia de como resolver, grato desde já!

Comment: As variáveis usadas nessa função não estão nela nem são parâmetros, talvez você tenha esquecido um `global`

Comment: @IcaroMartins, elas estão manualmente, não em variáveis, só coloquei assim para não aparecer os dados no banco, mas coloquei diferente agora, acho que fica melhor para as pessoas lerem desse jeito